Websocket connection fails only in firebase hosting
It used to work a few years ago, but on someday websocket connection on my app broke.
I thought the fault was on my side or the websocket api provider. But when I run it on my machine it works. And even doing firebase serve --only hosting works too.
Only the time I deploy it to the production, the websocket connection fails.
here is the code I used and its console log:
let socket = new WebSocket('wss://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1')

socket.onopen = (e) => {
  console.log('[open] 웹소켓이 열렸습니다');
  socket.send(
    `${JSON.stringify(
      [{ ticket: uuidv4() }, { type: 'ticker', codes: krw.map(c => c.market) }]
    )}`
  )
}

socket.onmessage = async (event) => {
  const ticker = await new Response(event.data).json()
  //...parse response and do something...
}

socket.onclose = (event) => {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    console.log(`[close] 커넥션이 정상적으로 종료되었습니다(code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason})`);
  } else {
    // 예시: 프로세스가 죽거나 네트워크에 장애가 있는 경우
    // event.code가 1006이 됩니다.
    console.warn(`[close] 커넥션이 죽었습니다. ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  }
}

socket.onerror = function (error) {
  console.warn(`[error] ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
}

the two console.warn appears in console like below:
index.5eafb082.js:1  WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1' failed: 
openSocket @ index.5eafb082.js:1
index.5eafb082.js:1 [error] {"isTrusted":true}
index.5eafb082.js:1 [close] 커넥션이 죽었습니다. {"isTrusted":true}

the error object seems to contain weird { "isTrusted": true } content and it helps nothing...
Again this happens only on production hosting... any idea?
Edit (Added console.error of plain error object)


To view the complete error, can you take out JSON.stringify in your onerror method and just print the error?

@SoftwareDveloper I added on the content.

I just solved it by adding a retry logic. after several reconnection it works.
